# SearchTextInput hiding behind keyboard react-native-dropdown-picker

Tags: react-native

I am trying to render a list of countries with search functionality but when focusing on searchTextInput, the KeyboardAvoidingView starts pushing dropdown and not TextInput. Is there any way to solve that issue?
I am using **react-native-dropdown-picker**

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" enabled={enableshift}>
      <Card
        style={{
          ...styles.card,
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
          borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
          paddingVertical: 30,
        }}>
            <Card.Content>
                <Text style={styles.title}> Select Your Location</Text>
            </Card.Content>
            
            <DropDownPicker
               items={[
                {
                  label: 'USA',
                  value: 'usa',
                  icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />,
                  hidden: true,
                },
                {
                  label: 'UK',
                  value: 'uk',
                  icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />,
                },
                {
                  label: 'France',
                  value: 'france',
                  icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />,
                },
              ]}
              searchTextInputProps={{onFocus: () => setenableShift(true)}}
              placeholder="Select an item"
              defaultValue={Ecountry}
              containerStyle={{height: 50}}
              style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
              itemStyle={{
                justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              }}
              dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
              onChangeItem={(item) => setEcountry(item.value)}
              searchable={true}
              searchablePlaceholder="Search for an item"
              searchablePlaceholderTextColor="gray"
              seachableStyle={{}}
              searchableError={() => <Text>Not Found</Text>}
          />
    </Card>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

**A search Text input and list of countries is hidden behind keyboard**

[image]

Comment: I tend to use [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) to handle keyboard. But in your cause try to change the behavior to positio or padding and see if it works

Comment: Yes, changing the behavior to padding should fix the problem